# Show equality between these two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, substitution

I have a simple (?) index substitution (?) problem, where I want to show that

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^n a_n b_m c_{n-m} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{j+k} b_k c_j
$$

but whatever I try, I end up with $j$ also in the limits of the second sum, instead of it going to $\infty$ .

The way I got to this equivalence was by writing out the first few terms of the left-hand sum and sorting them by  $c_j$ :

|  | m = n | m = n-1 | m = n - 2 | m = n-3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n = 0 | $a_0b_0c_0$ |  |  |  |  |
| n = 1 | $a_1b_1c_0$ | $a_1b_0c_1$ |  |  |  |
| n = 2 | $a_2b_2c_0$ | $a_2b_1c_1$ | $a_2b_0c_2$ |  |  |
| n = 3 | $a_3b_3c_0$ | $a_3b_2c_1$ | $a_3b_1c_2$ | $a_3b_0c_3$ |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

from there it looks fairly obvious that I can write it as the right-hand sum.
Or have I made a mistake there already?

I hope it's understandable what I want to achieve and I am not missing any crucial information. If so, let me know.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to include the absolute convergence so rearranging the series can be done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a small mistake in my previous answer, which I've deleted.

I'll explain this in the simplest possible language without leaving any logical gaps.

On the one hand, you have all 2-tuples of the form $(n,m)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ where $0\leq m\leq n$.

On the other hand, you have all 2-tuples of the form $(k,j)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ where $0\leq j$ and $0\leq k$.

$\\$

For simplicity, let me write $f(x,y,z)$ instead of $a_x b_y c_z$.

We can also write $f(n,m,n-m)$ as $g(n,m)$

and we can write $f(j+k,k,j)$ as $h(k,j)$.

$\\$

One way to prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{0\leq m\leq n}g(n,m)=\sum_{0\leq j\text{ and }0\leq k}h(k,j)$

is to show that you can pair up each 2-tuple $(n,m)$ with a 2-tuple $(k,j)$

such that each 2-tuple has a unique partner

and no 2-tuple is left out of the pairing

(in formal mathematical jargon, this is called a bijection)

and such that each specific pairing of $(n',m')$ with $(k',j')$ obeys $g(n',m')=h(k',j')$.

$\\$

You can achieve this by declaring the following:

$(n',m')$ shall be paired up with $(k',j')$, where $k'=m'$ and $j'=n'-m'$.

Prove that this pairing satisfies the criteria listed in the previous paragraph.